# Download customer address in pdf onclick button

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, order-grid

I displayed button **Download** [ last column in below image ]  in Sales **Order grid** page for each order. Once i click on button, I want to generate pdf with information of "**Customer address**" of that order.

[image]

I checked [Firegento](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf) & [comwrap](https://github.com/comwrap/magento-comwrap-pdf) , but both will generate only invoice, shipping, credit memos only.

app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Render - Delete.php

```
class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Render_Delete extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $getData = $row->getData();     
        $orderID = $getData['entity_id'];      
        $link = '<a href="'.$download.'">Download</a>;';
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Please guide me on this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**a.** app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Render - Delete.php

```
class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Render_Delete extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $getData = $row->getData();     
        $orderId = $getData['entity_id'];      
        $link = '<a href="'.$this->getPdfGenerateUrl($orderId).'">Download</a>;';
        return $link;
    }


    public function getPdfGenerateUrl($orderId)
    {
        return Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/raveinfosys/generatePdf', array('order_id' => $orderId));
    }

}
```

**b.** Now create a file called `RaveinfosysController.php`: app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/controllers/Adminhtml/RaveinfosysController.php with this content:

```
<?php
class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Adminhtml_RaveinfosysController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function generatePdfAction()
    {
        $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
        $page->setFont($font, 12);
        $width = $page->getWidth();
        $i=0;

        $page->drawText('Order Id# '.$order->getIncrementId(), 20, $page->getHeight()-20);
        $page->drawText("TO", 20, $page->getHeight()-40);
        $page->drawText($billingAddress->getStreet(). " ". $billingAddress->getRegion(), 20, $page->getHeight()-60);
        $page->drawText($billingAddress->getCountry(), 20, $page->getHeight()-80);
        $page->drawText($billingAddress->getRegionCode(), 20, $page->getHeight()-100);

        $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        //$pdf->render();

        $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('info'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');

        //$this->_redirectReferer();
    }

}
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks, i got : Fatal error: Call to a member function getFormated() on a non-object in  = > `$page->drawText($billingAddress->getFormated(), 20, $page->getHeight()-40);`

Comment: That means your `$order` is not an object. Check if order_id is correct in your url (in grid). It should be `raveinfosys/generatePdf/order_id/NUMBER`

Comment: onclick `download` button, I got this result in url : `sitename.com/index.php/admin/raveinfosys/generatePdf/key/6e70b958e72adcd9b69368ec317afd69/`

Comment: once i hide that line : `$page->drawText($billingAddress->getFormated(), 20, $page->getHeight()-40);` & when i click on `download` button , then it downloaded pdf with content as 'Order Id#`

Comment: YOu are not calling the url properly for some reason. check `return Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/raveinfosys/generatePdf', array('order_id' => $orderId));` part carefully.

Comment: I double checked it, i copy pasted your answer correctly.... is there any way to debug ?

Comment: Your url must contain `order_id/ORDER_ID_NUMBER`, so that in controller we can load the right order. Debugging would be inspecting `Download` url to see `order_id/ORDER_.......` section is built.

Comment: If above doesn't work then change `array('order_id' => $orderId)` to `array('order_number' => $orderId)` and `->getParam('order_id')` to `->getParam('order_number')`. This should render the url properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69324/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-adarsh-khatri).

Comment: Thanks a trillion for your help, it's really great that you helped in night also......